# Pegar um valor dentro do .Then

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promises, fetch

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const axios = require ('axios')
const { response } = require('express')
const fetch = require ('cross-fetch')


   
var aux
var aux1
fetch('http://10.50.2.180:4000/') 
.then(res => {
   
   return res.json();
 })
 .then(user => {
    
  console.log(user.usuario)
   console.log(user.senha)
   aux = user.usuario
   aux1 = user.senha
 
 })
 .catch(err => {

   console.error(err);
 });
     

console.log(aux,aux1)
```

Estou tentando criar uma *API* para validação de um login, as informações de login vem via outra *API*.
Para consumir a *API* que trás as infos usei o Fetch com um promise ali. A minha duvida e, como faço para pegar o valor que esta ali dentro do `.then(user)` e jogar em uma variável para usar fora desse escopo. Nesse exemplo, eu consigo imprimir `user.usuario` e `user.senha` dentro do `.then`, logo tento jogar esses valores dentro das variáveis `aux` e `aux1` para imprimir fora `.then`, porem quando uso o `console.log` no fim, so me trás `undefined` como resposta...

Comment: É basicamente um erro de uso, as variaveis estão em escopos diferentes, note também que requisições HTTP são assíncronas com fetch(). Da forma que está usando (com Promise), não irá nunca ter a resposta no mesmo tempo que o que está fora do escopo, me refiro ao `console.log(aux,aux1)`. Da forma que você está usando é com callback, veja mais detalhes em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434444/3635.

Comment: Note que com Promise você pode usar `await` também, que irá retornar o resultado do promise (se resolvido, caso contrário irá emitir uma exception) *diretamente*, o que poderia atribuir diretamente para as variáveis, leia mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Você declarou corretamente as variáveis**. Com `var` ela fica disponível no escopo da função onde foi declarada. No seu caso, o escopo por estar acima da função passada como parâmetro no `then`, ela está acessível nessa função também.

### Mas por que não funciona?

Porque uma `Promise` funciona de maneira assíncrona. Isso significa que seu script **não vai esperar** por ela ser resolvida para prosseguir. Sendo assim, o seu `console.log(aux,aux1)` na última linha **quase certamente vai ser chamado antes** da sua `Promise` ser resolvida! E você não pode contar com estes valores ali por causa disso.

Uma solução boa para isso é usar o [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) para que seu script espere pela `Promise` antes de prosseguir. Um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito, tentando o máximo da estrutura do seu código:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const axios = require ('axios')
const { response } = require('express')
const fetch = require ('cross-fetch')
    
async (() => {
    var aux, aux1;
    let response = await fetch('http://10.50.2.180:4000/') .then(res =>  res.json());
    aux = response.usuario;
    aux1 = response.senha;
    console.log(aux,aux1)
})();
```

neste caso, tudo a ser executado após a linha com o `await` só será executado quando a `Promise` retornar. Mas para que isso aconteça, é preciso que seja uma função assíncrona, por isso envolvi com uma função anônima com o `async` antes.

Comment: Obrigado Pela Explicação Wallace, ficou claro....E ajudou muito nas duvidas de aprendizagem que estou tendo....